# Как создать/добавить ИИ в бота discord python?

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py, искусственный-интеллект

Как сделать так, чтобы бот, при вводе какой-либо фразы после префикса (например, i!Как падают крокодилы?) бот отвечал на уровне человека, то есть добавить ИИ в бота.
Но еще желательно, чтобы остальные команды (например, i!test) работали так, как я сделаю.
Используется `bot= discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "i!")`

Comment: прежде чем добавить ии...откуда вы его возьмёте ?

Comment: Слышал, что есть модели поведения в Ask-sdk-model. Может быть оттуда взять?

Comment: `Как сделать` Так же, как вы делаете и остальные команды для бота.

Comment: Геннадий, таким образом можно сделать только определенные команды, например i!Привет. Но я же не могу предусмотреть остроумие какого-нибудь человека, который задастся вопросом, который я не предусмотрел, например i!Как можно сделать золото из ртути? Или что-то подобное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я наверное не совсем понял вопроса, но вот что я понял:
Вы хотите что бы бот отвечал на вопросы с префиксом, но вопросы будут разные, и вы не можете и вы не можете предугадать первое слово вопроса, то есть вопросы `!кто убил Кенади` и `!сколько будет 3^^^3?` будут иметь разные команды, в первом случае это `кто`, а во втором `сколько`.
В это случае вы можете:

1. Создать одну команду, например `!вопрос`, и использовать её так: `!вопрос почему небо голубое`
2. Использовать метод `on_message`.
   Этот метод ловит каждое сообщение
   Вот что вам нужно использовать:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content[0:2] == 'i!': #проверка на первый символ
        answer = ai( message.content[2:] ) #делаем запрос в ИИ, и записываем ответ в переменную
        message.channel.send(message.mention+', '+ answer) #отсылаем ответ пользователю
```